# App rejected on Playstore due to minimum font size

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I am using React Native for my Android TV app. For the message on the TV, I have set the fontSize as 48. But, Google playstore rejects the app with the reason

> "Not min font size for text Your app or game’s minimum font size does
> not provide a good user experience."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you turned off font scaling? That could fail accessibility testing. It's also possible they are looking for you to set a minimum font size, but the docs say this is only implemented for iOS ([link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#minimumfontscale-ios))

Comment: No..haven't turned off font scaling. Also tried putting the font size in dimens.xml and retrieving and using that in the app but no luck

Comment: Is it possible there is a font size set somewhere that is very small, like <8px?  You've said you set it to 48, but did you do that universally?

Comment: I had written to the google-play team to let me know the specific font they are referring to. Turns out it was a text in an image :) Have fixed that now. Awaiting the approval. Thanks!